# Javascript validation onblur

Tags: javascript

I have written same javascript twice for two textboxes but it runs both the scripts for one text box i need to write once and call the same for more text boxes

```
    function checkalphabets() {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    if (!pattern.test(myTextBox.value)) {
        modal({
            type: 'warning',
            title: 'Warning',
            text: 'Only Alphabets allowed!',
            center: false,
             callback: function(){ $("#myTextBox").focus();}
        });

        exit;
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
function checkalphabets1() {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    if (!pattern.test(TextBox1.value)) {
        modal({
            type: 'warning',
            title: 'Warning',
            text: 'Only Alphabets allowed!',
            center: false,
             callback: function(){ $("#TextBox1").focus();}
        });

        exit;
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
 $('.modal-btn').click(function() {

        $('#modal-window').hide();

    });
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kpsv1p4/37/)

Comment: you should define myTextBox and TestBox1 before trying to extract their values.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element to be checked as a parameter of the function:

```
function checkalphabets($el) {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    if (!pattern.test($el.val())) {
        modal({
            type: 'warning',
            title: 'Warning',
            text: 'Only Alphabets allowed!',
            center: false,
             callback: function(){ $el.focus();}
        });

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The elements is passed when called and the check is done on the element.

```
checkalphabets($("#TextBox1"));
```

Comment: you have syntax errors in your fiddle. you need to use single quotes `'` in your inline `onblur` code

Comment: please check both textbox validated at same time http://jsfiddle.net/7kpsv1p4/52/

Answer (score 0):

in your code textbox1 and mytextbox are undefined. Pass elements to the function to make them defined:

```
function checkalphabets(myinput) {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    if (!pattern.test(myinput.value)) {
        modal({
            type: 'warning',
            title: 'Warning',
            text: 'Only Alphabets allowed!',
            center: false,
             callback: function(){ $(myinput).focus();}
        });

        exit;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

 $('.modal-btn').click(function() {

        $('#modal-window').hide();

    });
```

also I suggest onkeyup instead of onblur to make check after each character:

```
<input name="myTextBox" type="text" id="myTextBox" onkeyup="checkalphabets(this)" />
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" onkeyup="checkalphabets(this)" />
```

Aslo it would be good idea to subtract disallowed characters after warning.

Answer (score 0):

Can you think of passing the this value as input to the function in Javascript & extract the value from this variable as explained below?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="test.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJODIwMTY2MjU3ZGQVs14nJwqB/iIms8CsXW3SCzs22w==" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="75BBA7D6" />
</div>
    <div>
        <input name="myTextBox" type="text" id="myTextBox" onblur="checkalphabets(this)" />
        <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" onblur="checkalphabets(this)" />   
    </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkalphabets(thisValue) {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    if (!pattern.test(thisValue.value)) {
        modal({
            type: 'warning',
            title: 'Warning',
            text: 'Only Alphabets allowed t1 & t2!',
            center: false,
             callback: function(){ $(thisValue).focus();}
        });

        exit;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
 $('.modal-btn').click(function() {
        $('#modal-window').hide();
    });
```

Like wise you can use the same method of any number of text boxes!

Comment: No its not working both the text boxes are validate at same time

Comment: I am running the same code in JSfiddle and I am able to see that the method is getting triggered only once on blur of that particular textbox.  But, If we move from one textbox1 to another textbox2.. Onblur event of textbox1 will be triggered which will show a modal... On click of "Ok" in model alert, on blur event of textbox2 will be called... Is that the problem you are talking about?

Comment: where did any mention of asp.net come from?

Comment: Please refer to the Fiddle link provided by the user!